# Special configuration of i3wm

Tags: i3-wm

I'm trying to install a certain configuration of `i3`, but the procedure is unclear (nothing is working!!). As I am not a regular user of Ubuntu, I need a little bit of help. The font is really awesome, but hard to install : http://dotshare.it/dots/1011/.

Could anyone have time to help me on this point?

**Error :**

```
ERROR: CONFIG: Expected one of these tokens: <end>, '#', 'set', 'bindsym', 'bindcode', 'bind', 'bar', 'font', 'mode', 'floating_minimum_size', 'floating_maximum_size', 'floating_modifier', 'default_orientation', 'workspace_layout', 'new_window', 'new_float', 'hide_edge_borders', 'for_window', 'assign', 'no_focus', 'focus_follows_mouse', 'mouse_warping', 'force_focus_wrapping', 'force_xinerama', 'force-xinerama', 'workspace_auto_back_and_forth', 'fake_outputs', 'fake-outputs', 'force_display_urgency_hint', 'focus_on_window_activation', 'show_marks', 'workspace', 'ipc_socket', 'ipc-socket', 'restart_state', 'popup_during_fullscreen', 'exec_always', 'exec', 'client.background', 'client.focused_inactive', 'client.focused', 'client.unfocused', 'client.urgent', 'client.placeholder'
ERROR: CONFIG: (in file /home/jeremie/.config/i3/config)
ERROR: CONFIG: Line  43:     set 12 12
ERROR: CONFIG: Line  44:     set 0 0
ERROR: CONFIG: Line  45:     gaps inner 12
ERROR: CONFIG:               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR: CONFIG: Line  46:     gaps outer 0
ERROR: CONFIG: Line  47: 
ERROR: CONFIG: Expected one of these tokens: <end>, '#', 'set', 'bindsym', 'bindcode', 'bind', 'bar', 'font', 'mode', 'floating_minimum_size', 'floating_maximum_size', 'floating_modifier', 'default_orientation', 'workspace_layout', 'new_window', 'new_float', 'hide_edge_borders', 'for_window', 'assign', 'no_focus', 'focus_follows_mouse', 'mouse_warping', 'force_focus_wrapping', 'force_xinerama', 'force-xinerama', 'workspace_auto_back_and_forth', 'fake_outputs', 'fake-outputs', 'force_display_urgency_hint', 'focus_on_window_activation', 'show_marks', 'workspace', 'ipc_socket', 'ipc-socket', 'restart_state', 'popup_during_fullscreen', 'exec_always', 'exec', 'client.background', 'client.focused_inactive', 'client.focused', 'client.unfocused', 'client.urgent', 'client.placeholder'
ERROR: CONFIG: (in file /home/jeremie/.config/i3/config)
ERROR: CONFIG: Line  44:     set 0 0
ERROR: CONFIG: Line  45:     gaps inner 12
ERROR: CONFIG: Line  46:     gaps outer 0
ERROR: CONFIG:               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR: CONFIG: Line  47: 
ERROR: CONFIG: Line  48:     set I I
ERROR: FYI: You are using i3 version 4.12 (2016-03-06, branch "4.12")
ERROR: You did not specify required configuration option "font"
ERROR: Received ConfigureNotify for unknown window 0x00600000
ERROR: Received ExposeEvent for unknown window 0x00600000
ERROR: Received ExposeEvent for unknown window 0x00600000
ERROR: Received ExposeEvent for unknown window 0x00600000
ERROR: Received ConfigureNotify for unknown window 0x00600000
ERROR: Received ConfigureNotify for unknown window 0x00600003
ERROR: Received ExposeEvent for unknown window 0x00600003
ERROR: Received ConfigureNotify for unknown window 0x00600003
```

My `.config/i3/config` file :

```
# i3 config file (v4)
#
# Please see http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html for a complete reference!
#
# This config file uses keycodes (bindsym) and was written for the QWERTY
# layout.
#
# To get a config file with the same key positions, but for your current
# layout, use the i3-config-wizard
#

# Font for window titles. Will also be used by the bar unless a different font
# is used in the bar {} block below.
# This font is widely installed, provides lots of unicode glyphs, right-to-left
# text rendering and scalability on retina/hidpi displays (thanks to pango).
#font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono 8
# Before i3 v4.8, we used to recommend this one as the default:
# font -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-C-70-iso10646-1
# The font above is very space-efficient, that is, it looks good, sharp and
# clear in small sizes. However, its unicode glyph coverage is limited, the old
# X core fonts rendering does not support right-to-left and this being a bitmap
# font, it doesn’t scale on retina/hidpi displays.

### THEME ###

set $FOCUS #989898
set $UNFOCUS #3c3b37

# Layout colors         bord    bg      text    indicator (split)
client.focused          $FOCUS $FOCUS $FOCUS $FOCUS
client.focused_inactive $UNFOCUS $UNFOCUS $UNFOCUS $UNFOCUS
client.unfocused        $UNFOCUS $UNFOCUS $UNFOCUS $UNFOCUS
client.urgent           $FOCUS $FOCUS $FOCUS $FOCUS
client.background       $UNFOCUS

### Borders ###
new_window pixel 4
new_float pixel 4

focus_follows_mouse no

### Gaps ###
set $default_gaps_inner 12
set $default_gaps_outer 0
gaps inner $default_gaps_inner
gaps outer $default_gaps_outer

set $ws1 I
set $ws2 II
set $ws3 III
set $ws4 IV
set $ws5 V
set $ws6 VI
set $ws7 VII
set $ws8 VIII
set $ws9 IX
set $ws10 X


# use these keys for focus, movement, and resize directions when reaching for
# the arrows is not convenient
set $up k
set $down j
set $left h
set $right l

# use Mouse+Mod1 to drag floating windows to their wanted position
floating_modifier Mod1

# start a terminal
bindsym Mod1+Return exec --no-startup-id urxvt

# kill focused window
bindsym Mod1+q kill

# start dmenu (a program launcher)
#bindsym Mod1+d exec dmenu_run
# There also is the (new) i3-dmenu-desktop which only displays applications
# shipping a .desktop file. It is a wrapper around dmenu, so you need that
# installed.
bindsym Mod1+d exec --no-startup-id i3-dmenu-desktop

# change focus
bindsym Mod1+$left focus left
bindsym Mod1+$down focus down
bindsym Mod1+$up focus up
bindsym Mod1+$right focus right

# alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
bindsym Mod1+Left focus left
bindsym Mod1+Down focus down
bindsym Mod1+Up focus up
bindsym Mod1+Right focus right

# move focused window
bindsym Mod1+Shift+$left move left
bindsym Mod1+Shift+$down move down
bindsym Mod1+Shift+$up move up
bindsym Mod1+Shift+$right move right

# alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
bindsym Mod1+Shift+Left move left
bindsym Mod1+Shift+Down move down
bindsym Mod1+Shift+Up move up
bindsym Mod1+Shift+Right move right

# split in horizontal orientation
bindsym Mod1+c split h

# split in vertical orientation
bindsym Mod1+v split v

# enter fullscreen mode for the focused container
bindsym Mod1+f fullscreen

# change container layout (stacked, tabbed, toggle split)
bindsym Mod1+s layout stacking
bindsym Mod1+w layout tabbed
bindsym Mod1+e layout toggle split

# toggle tiling / floating
bindsym Mod1+Shift+space floating toggle

# change focus between tiling / floating windows
bindsym Mod1+space focus mode_toggle

# focus the parent container
bindsym Mod1+a focus parent

# focus the child container
#bindsym Mod1+d focus child

# move the currently focused window to the scratchpad
bindsym Mod1+Shift+minus move scratchpad

# Show the next scratchpad window or hide the focused scratchpad window.
# If there are multiple scratchpad windows, this command cycles through them.
bindsym Mod1+minus scratchpad show

# switch to workspace
bindsym Mod1+1 workspace $ws1
bindsym Mod1+2 workspace $ws2
bindsym Mod1+3 workspace $ws3
bindsym Mod1+4 workspace $ws4
bindsym Mod1+5 workspace $ws5
bindsym Mod1+6 workspace $ws6
bindsym Mod1+7 workspace $ws7
bindsym Mod1+8 workspace $ws8
bindsym Mod1+9 workspace $ws9
bindsym Mod1+0 workspace $ws10

# move focused container to workspace
bindsym Mod1+Shift+1 move container to workspace $ws1
bindsym Mod1+Shift+2 move container to workspace $ws2
bindsym Mod1+Shift+3 move container to workspace $ws3
bindsym Mod1+Shift+4 move container to workspace $ws4
bindsym Mod1+Shift+5 move container to workspace $ws5
bindsym Mod1+Shift+6 move container to workspace $ws6
bindsym Mod1+Shift+7 move container to workspace $ws7
bindsym Mod1+Shift+8 move container to workspace $ws8
bindsym Mod1+Shift+9 move container to workspace $ws9
bindsym Mod1+Shift+0 move container to workspace $ws10

# reload the configuration file
bindsym Mod1+Shift+c reload
# restart i3 inplace (preserves your layout/session, can be used to upgrade i3)
bindsym Mod1+Shift+r restart
# exit i3 (logs you out of your X session)
bindsym Mod1+Shift+e exec --no-startup-id  "i3-nagbar -t warning -m 'You pressed the exit shortcut. Do you really want to exit i3? This will end your X session.' -b 'Yes, exit i3' 'i3-msg exit'"

# resize window (you can also use the mouse for that)
mode "resize" {
# These bindings trigger as soon as you enter the resize mode

# Pressing left will shrink the window’s width.
# Pressing down will grow the window’s height.
    bindsym $left       resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym $down       resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym $up         resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym $right      resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

# same bindings, but for the arrow keys
        bindsym Left        resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Down        resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Up          resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Right       resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

# back to normal: Enter or Escape
        bindsym Return mode "default"
        bindsym Escape mode "default"
}

bindsym Mod1+r mode "resize"

### Shortcuts ###
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id amixer -c 1 sset 'Master' 5%+
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id amixer -c 1 sset 'Master' 5%-
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id amixer sset 'Master' toggle
bindsym XF86AudioPlay exec --no-startup-id playcontrols toggle
bindsym XF86AudioStop exec --no-startup-id playcontrols stop
bindsym XF86AudioPrev exec --no-startup-id playcontrols prev
bindsym XF86AudioNext exec --no-startup-id playcontrols next
bindsym XF86Calculator exec --no-startup-id gnome-calculator 
bindsym XF86TouchpadToggle exec --no-startup-id /home/luca/Documenti/toggletouchpad

bindsym Mod4+F12 exec --no-startup-id amixer -c 1 sset 'Master' 5%+
bindsym Mod4+F11 exec --no-startup-id amixer -c 1 sset 'Master' 5%-
bindsym Mod4+F10 exec --no-startup-id amixer sset 'Master' toggle
bindsym Mod4+Down exec --no-startup-id playcontrols toggle
bindsym Mod4+Up exec --no-startup-id playcontrols stop
bindsym Mod4+Left exec --no-startup-id playcontrols prev
bindsym Mod4+Right exec --no-startup-id playcontrols next
bindsym Mod4+KP_Enter exec --no-startup-id gnome-calculator 
bindsym Mod4+F9 exec --no-startup-id /home/luca/Documenti/toggletouchpad

bindsym Mod1+shift+g exec --no-startup-id geany
bindsym Mod1+p exec --no-startup-id pcmanfm
bindsym Mod1+shift+a exec --no-startup-id audacious
bindsym Mod1+shift+n exec --no-startup-id urxvt -name ncmpcpp -e ncmpcpp -s playlist 
bindsym Mod1+shift+f exec --no-startup-id urxvt -name ranger -e ranger
bindsym Mod1+shift+v exec --no-startup-id vlc
bindsym Mod1+shift+s exec --no-startup-id spotify --ui.track_notifications_enabled=false
bindsym Mod1+shift+i exec --no-startup-id icedove
bindsym Mod1+shift+b exec --no-startup-id iceweasel
bindsym Mod1+shift+p exec --no-startup-id urxvt -name games-launcher -e /home/luca/Documenti/games.sh
bindsym Mod1+Print exec --no-startup-id scrot 'Schermata%Y-%m-%d-%T.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Immagini/'

assign [class="Audacious"] $ws6
assign [class="Vlc"] $ws6
assign [class="Iceweasel"] $ws1
assign [class="Telegram"] $ws2
assign [class="Spotify"] $ws6
assign [class="pidgin"] $ws2
assign [class="URxvt" instance="ncmpcpp"] $ws3
assign [class="URxvt" instance="tty-clock"] $ws3
assign [class="URxvt" instance="mcabber"] $ws2


### floating windows ###
for_window [class="Steam"] floating enable
for_window [class="Gimp"] floating enable
for_window [class="PlayOnLinux"] floating enable
for_window [class="URxvt" instance="games-launcher$"] move to workspace $ws5, floating enable , move absolute position 400px 200px


### Exec ###
exec --no-startup-id compton -bG --config ~/.config/compton.conf 

exec --no-startup-id iceweasel 
exec --no-startup-id conky -c ~/.config/panel/empty_conky 
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace $ws3'
exec --no-startup-id mkfontdir ~/.local/share/fonts && xset +fp ~/.local/share/fonts && xset fp rehash && ~/.config/panel/bar_config
exec --no-startup-id ~/Telegram
exec --no-startup-id sh ~/.fehbg
exec --no-startup-id mpd
exec --no-startup-id urxvt -name ncmpcpp -e ncmpcpp -s playlist
exec --no-startup-id urxvt -name tty-clock -e tty-clock -C 2 -c -d 20000000000
exec --no-startup-id xinput disable 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad' 
exec --no-startup-id xinput set-prop 'USB Optical Mouse' 261 0.8
exec --no-startup-id sleep 3 && urxvt -name mcabber -e mcabbert
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please, do not post the same question on different StackExchange sites at the same time. Have a look at [this question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

## Cause of the error

It seems that you are trying to use configuration files for *i3-gaps* with "vanilla" *i3*.  *i3-gaps* is an unofficial fork of *i3*, the main feature of which is the ability to have gaps between tiled windows. In order to facilitate this, *i3-gaps* has the `gaps` configuration setting, among others. This settings is of course not available in the official version of *i3*, hence the error message.

If you installed `i3-wm` from the Ubuntu repository or one of the repositories mentioned on [the i3 homepage](https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html), then you got the official version of *i3*.

## Quick solution

If you only want to get rid of the error message, there are essentially two ways to do this:

- Remove/comment out these five lines

  ```
  ### Gaps ###
  set $default_gaps_inner 12
  set $default_gaps_outer 0
  gaps inner $default_gaps_inner
  gaps outer $default_gaps_outer
  ```

  The result should work with the official version of *i3* but it might not look as intended.
- Install *i3-gaps*, which on Ubuntu probably means that you have to compile it on your own. Have a look at [the i3-gaps wiki](https://github.com/Airblader/i3/wiki/Compiling-&-Installing) for more information.

Which one you choose depends on how important the ability to have gaps between windows is to you. If you do not really want them, I would suggest to install *i3* from the stable Ubuntu repository as mentioned [here](https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html).

## Slower (but possibly better) solution

Personally, I would recommend against using foreign *i3* configuration files (or any other program for that matter) without at least having a very good look at them for several reasons:

- **Security/Safety:** *i3* has the builtin ability to run arbitrary commands with `exec`. For example: the configuration file you copied tries to disable a certain type of Touchpad:

  ```
  exec --no-startup-id xinput disable 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
  ```

  This could be inconvenient, if your Touchpad has the same name but you actually want to use it.
- **Dependencies:** As *i3* is just a window manager, people tend to supplement it with all kinds of tools. The above configuration for example tries to load the following programs either directly or via shortcut: `amixer`, `playcontrols`, `gnome-calculator`, `geany`, `pcmanfm`, `audacious`, `ncmpcpp`, `vlc`, `urxvt`, `spotify`, `icedove`, `iceweasel`, `scrot`, `conky`, `Telegram`, `mpd`, `mcabber`, `tty-clock`, `compton`.

  Any of those might not be installed on your machine. And even if they are installed, you may not actually want to start them. `compton`, for example, could even cause problems with some graphics cards and/or drivers.
- **Usability** *i3* configurations tend to be very personalized. What works great for someone else, might be near unusable to you. *i3* configurations are more than just themes; they also define shortcuts, can configure default workspaces for programs and - as mentioned before - can start other applications automatically. Also, for the most part *i3* has no default behavior, most notably every shortcut needs to be defined in the configuration. Also the *i3-bar*, which usually lists all the workspaces, needs to be explicitly enabled.

I would suggest starting out with a vanilla configuration file, having a look at the [*i3* User's Guide](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html) and then modifying your configuration until *i3* (or *i3-gaps, if you want) works and looks like you want it. *i3* has a lot of features, many of which are not even enabled in the default configuration (or the above example, for that matter). Of course there is no reason to not still have a look at configuration files of other people in order to get some inspiration (and maybe even copy some **parts** outright).